# Karate 1.0.1 Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, karate

I upgraded from 0.9.6 to 1.0.1 and seeing some test failures for the tests that worked before.
1.

```
Illegal character in path at index 110: 
http call failed after 1 milliseconds for url: https://dev.company.cloud/account/info/7272727/submissions/2939999/policies/11B GGRR/35353/key/01
It fails because of the space in the URL.
```

2. - json request = read('classpath:test_data/src/main/resources/api/calc/templates/data/payload.json')

   > > > > js failed:
   > > > > 01: read('classpath:xxxxx/payload.json')

   <<<<
   org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: xxxxx/payload.json

   - com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.getResource(ResourceUtils.java:120)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.toResource(ScenarioFileReader.java:128)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:103)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsString(ScenarioFileReader.java:99)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:53)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:118)
   - .:program(Unnamed:1)
3. Examples:
   |read('classpath:xxx/src/main/resources/xxxx/calc/dev_test_data/xxxx.csv')|

   > > > > js failed:
   > > > > 01: read('classpath:xxx/src/main/resources/xxxx/calc/dev_test_data/xxxx.csv')
   > > > > <<<<
   > > > > org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: xxx/src/main/resources/xxxx/calc/dev_test_data/xxxx.csv

   - com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.getResource(ResourceUtils.java:120)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.toResource(ScenarioFileReader.java:128)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:103)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsString(ScenarioFileReader.java:99)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:68)
   - com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:118)
   - .:program(Unnamed:1)
4. In the cucumber report, feature column shows failed, but it shows all scenarios passed even though they all failed.

Comment: I did. Still reviewing the solutions you shared. Thanks

Comment: maybe it is a bug. sorry no one can help you unless you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and since we had asked for a long time for teams to provide feedback on RC releases and you didn't - please be prepared to wait a long time for the next release

Comment: Sorry, I did not plan to upgrade until you shared the solution for my other question that is in release 1.0.0

Comment: that's fine, you can continue on an old version and wait for others to help you.